# Is there a way to add a jump mechanic to my game?

Tags: java

I had been trying to add a way for the rectangle (player) to jump to 130 pixels up and add delay than go back down 130 pixels. I tried to make it go up, thread.sleep, then make it go back down but the screen doesn't refresh and It doesn't work. For example, I added a couple of sys outs and saw that it went up and went back down but seems like it doesn't refresh the frame during the thread.sleep

```
package com.cookie.clicker;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ChromeOfflineGame extends JPanel {
public static Timer t;
static int x = 0;
static int y = 900;
static int width = 1920;
static int height = 250;

static int pX = 50;
static int pY = 800;
static int pW = 50;
static int pH = 100;

static Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
static Rectangle player = new Rectangle(pX,pY,pW,pH);
static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public ChromeOfflineGame() {
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                if (player.getY()<ground.getY()) {
                    //method to jump
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ChromeOfflineGame finder = new ChromeOfflineGame();
                
                
                frame.getContentPane().add(finder);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                
                
                t = new Timer(2,(ActionEvent e)->{
                    finder.redraw();
                    ground.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
                    player.setBounds(pX,pY,pW,pH);
                });
                t.start();                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1920, 1080);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    g.setColor(Color.green); 
    g.fillRect (
        (int)ground.getX(),
        (int)ground.getY(),
        (int)ground.getWidth(),
        (int)ground.getHeight()
    );  
    
    
    

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect((int)player.getX(),(int) player.getY(), (int)player.getWidth(), (int)player.getHeight());
}
public void redraw() {
    this.repaint();
}

public void jump() {
    //Makes player -=130;
    //than makes player +=130;
}

}
```

Comment: You have to do this in such a way that you're not holding up the ui thread waiting for the jump operation to complete. A timer is one way to do it. Lower the y coordinate (all at once or a bit at a time) and as the timer is triggered, bring it back again.

Comment: That would make sense to use a Timer, but here's the problem, how will I stop it and make it go back down? can you show some examples of code like that?

Comment: Why don't you have a go with a timer, and if you can't do it, post a question with a [mre] for your attempt.